# Distinct Subset Sums: Extending A276661

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics, set-theory

Consider the integer set \$S = \{3, 5, 6, 7\}\$. If we list all \$2^n\$ subsets of \$S\$ (its powerset) and calculate their sums, we get

$$
\mathcal{P}(S) = \{\emptyset, \{3\}, \{5\}, \{6\}, \{7\}, \{3, 5\}, \{3, 6\}, \{3, 7\}, \{5, 6\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 7\}, \{3, 5, 6\}, \{3, 5, 7\}, \{3, 6, 7\}, \{5, 6, 7\}, \{3, 5, 6, 7\}\} \\
\sum_{s \in \mathcal{P}(S)} s = \{0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 21\}
$$

You'll note that this set of sums is distinct - no element is repeated. We'll say that \$S\$ is a **distinct subset sum set**. Note that we're only considering sets containing positive integers for this.

In fact, for \$n = 4\$, \$k = 7\$ is the smallest positive integer such that there is a set \$S\$ containing \$n\$ distinct elements from the set \$\{1, 2, ..., k\}\$ and that \$S\$ is a distinct subset sum set. The values of \$k\$ for \$n = 0, 1, 2, 3\$ are:

| \$n\$ | \$k\$ | \$S\$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$0\$ | \$0\$ | \$\emptyset\$ |
| \$1\$ | \$1\$ | \$\{1\}\$ |
| \$2\$ | \$2\$ | \$\{1,2\}\$ |
| \$3\$ | \$4\$ | \$\{1,2,4\}\$ |

For any given \$n\$, we can say that \$2^{n-1}\$ is an upper bound, as the set \$\{2^0, 2^1, ..., 2^{n-1}\}\$ is always a distinct subset sum set.

However, as shown above, this upper bound can be improved. In fact, one of the current best upper bounds is the Conway-Guy sequence ([A005318](https://oeis.org/A005318)), given by:

$$
a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1\\
a_{n+1} = 2a_n - a_{n - \lfloor 1/2 + \sqrt{2n} \rfloor}
$$

However, it's been shown that \$a_{67} = 34808838084768972989\$ can be improved as a bound to \$34808712605260918463\$, so the Conway-Guy sequence is currently only an upper bound (and a non-optimal one at that), rather than the exact terms. The exact terms are given by [A276661](https://oeis.org/A276661).

This sequence has only been proven to be optimal up to \$n = 9\$. Your task is to improve this.

Your program should take a non-negative integer \$n\$ and output the smallest integer \$k\$ such that there exists a distinct subset sum set \$S\$ such that, for all elements \$S_i\$, \$1 \le S_i \le k\$. Note that this is *not* the Conway-Guy sequence; if given \$n = 67\$ as an input, the output should not be \$34808838084768972989\$.

Your program may fail *practically* due to integer constraints (e.g. if the output exceeds your language's integer maximum), but should work *theoretically* for all \$n\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

---

Additionally, I will offer a bounty for the answer for which:

- it can produce the correct output for a value \$x > 9\$ within a minute (time using TIO if possible), and
- it can produce the correct output for all values \$1 \le i \le x\$ within a minute for each

The bounty will be awarded to the answer which can do this for the highest \$x\$. The amount I'll award will depend on the exact value of \$x\$ (e.g. \$x = 20\$ will be awarded more than \$x = 10\$), but it will be at least 150 reputation. Once someone can produce the output for \$x = 10\$, I'll wait 2 weeks for any answers to try to beat it, then start the bounty.

---

### Test cases

```
n   k
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   7
5  13
6  24
7  44
8  84
9 161
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/175548/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/168390/66833). Brownie points for beating/matching my 13 byte, incredible inefficient (times out for \$n > 6\$ on TIO) Jelly answer

Comment: Also related to [PE 103](https://projecteuler.net/problem=103).

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `R`, 13 bytes

```
λ?↔'ṗv∑:U⁼;;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=%CE%BB%3F%E2%86%94%27%E1%B9%97v%E2%88%91%3AU%E2%81%BC%3B%3B%E1%B9%85&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Outputs in a singleton list.

```
λ          ;ṅ # First integer for which the following is true:
   '      ;   # Any of...
 ?↔           # combinations_with_replacements(1..n,input)
   '      ;   # Has the property that...
    ṗv∑       # Sums of all subsets
       :U⁼    # Are all unique
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't realise that Cartesian power would work instead of combinations without replacement (as if the set includes any duplicates, it can't have distinct subset sums), so I can get my Jelly answer down to 12 bytes (and even more inefficient)

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing I didn't realise combinations_without_replacement worked - thanks for saving several bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 169 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
f=lambda i,n=2:any(len(k:=[*map(sum,chain(*[combinations(x,r)for r in range(n)]))])==len({*k})for x in product(*[range(1,n)]*i))and~-n or f(i,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc7LCsIwEIXhvU@R5STWRdWFCHmS4iK9xA5tZsI0hRbRV6@pwll@/Jy4pp7pcouybV44KEydJOZxUhgiSzIHb0cX6tYpLMie745WGDuC4W4rE1yEaQ5F0zskMFXDoUZyCZkmWArRnkWJQlLi6NkB6YfOs3YvvMzw/oFlB1G4nZuUI39aFhkb1NpR@zmRys5DvnAs9RYFKYGHq9bbFw)

Mighty itertools

-15 thanks to @ovs

Comment: [169 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc7LCsIwEIXhvU@R5STWRdWFCHmS4iK9xA5tZsI0hRbRV6@pwll@/Jy4pp7pcouybV44KEydJOZxUhgiSzIHb0cX6tYpLMie745WGDuC4W4rE1yEaQ5F0zskMFXDoUZyCZkmWArRnkWJQlLi6NkB6YfOs3YvvMzw/oFlB1G4nZuUI39aFhkb1NpR@zmRys5DvnAs9RYFKYGHq9bbFw) with two itertools related golfs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>111</s> <s>102</s> 96  bytes

Finishes for \$n=7\$ in three seconds, every larger \$n\$ takes too long on TIO.

```python
f=lambda n,i=1,s=[(0,1)]:n>max(zip(*s)[0])and-~f(n,i+1,s+[(w+1,l|l<<i)for w,l in s if l<<i&l<1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoMwEADvfcWeym4TQXsqkvgR8ZBi0y7ENUTBppR@PdXTwMzEvL5muVYxx1yKt8FN99GBaLaNXmyPtW5oaKWb3Bs/HPGyUF8P5GSsfh73T@2f6nHbGb7BGCY/J9h0ABZYgD0c8hxMM1A5Eh8hOXk@8EbtCSAmlhVYg/LIVP4)

The list `s` keeps track of all valid sets up to size `k`, storing a set as its length and the possible sums represented by a bitmask. This improves performance over regular sets and makes adding a new number as simple as `l|l<<i`.

With some small optimizations this finishes in under a second for \$n=7\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7BCsIwEATQe75iT9JaAsaLULtfsuyhEEs3hm0oESmIvx5TevIyp3nDpC3Pi15t2tJWiuATL0ZRNDei6ZWbtjUeiRxzR8R8/lo171niA8YYmzgMcoowLStEEAVP1nHbGwio1hk4mqH3FBj36Ggnnz8SqpEJjq3B8T1YrFa6mmmtV0BhVA9Syu0H)
\$n=8\$ is still far out on TIO (1m30s and 15GB RAM locally)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṗŒP§QƑƊƇ¥1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bmXxZJQwqdRxpHGisaHwqUxI////zQ)

A monadic link taking and returning an integer. Terribly inefficient since it takes the powerset of the Cartesian power. Replacing `ṗ` with `œc` improves efficiency at the cost of a byte, but still very slow.

Comment: Nice trick with the `Ƈ`, I had [this](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4bmXxZJQwqdRxpHGiuKCrOG6uMmXMSP/xbs7w4ck4oKsR///NA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES10), 136 bytes

Slightly shorter. Much slower.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>{for(v=++k**n;v--*!(new Set([...Array(n)].reduce((a,_,i)=>a.flatMap(x=>[x,x+v/k**i%k|0]),[0])).size>>n););return~v?0:1+g(k)})``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7BboMwEETv@QpHSqVdDC459FK6rvoBOfWIomIRgyhoHRniklL669S9zFye5s2nCWasfXedMnYXuzW0MWloqSe9NM5DICn7JOEiZFmyB7Zf4t1OUCql3rw3d2A8K28vt9oCmPQj7ZC0Uc1gppO5wky6nNNZhsc40j30P/kZ0zIGqrH7tlozFlh4O908/4bX/PkoW@hxxara/vUsSOSFYPFC4im2lCiWnRC149ENVg2uhcrAYeEVI3pYmnhorXC3bn8)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 138 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>{for(v=++k**n;v--*!(new Set([...Array(n)].reduce((a,_,i)=>[...a,...a.map(x=>x+v/k**i%k|0)],[0])).size>>n););return~v?0:1+g(k)})``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7BToRAEETv@xVtsibdDIx42IvYY/wGjxsiE3YgyNqzGdhxFfHXES5Vh3qpvA8b7VCH7jJm4k9uaXgRNthyz2ZqfMDISvVJIkXMsuQOxX3BmxvxqLV@DcF@o1Cpgztda4do0/e0IzbbatMt9Ke94I3NTcWH9aa7739zKtNjXhLpoftxxggVVAQ3XoP8xZf86VG12NNMVbVsAgIMeQECzwyHtZUimHYAtZfBn50@@xYri/tJZlrR/dSsSnNFu3n5Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>64</s> 46 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹η⊞υ¹Ｗ¬⊙υ⁼Σ↨κ²Ｘ²θ«≦⊗ηＦυ¿¬＆κ×ηκ⊞υ×⊕ηκ»Ｉ⊖Ｌ↨η²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY67jsIwEEVr8hVTjiVTQLFNqvAokFgUafkBkwzYwrGJHxshxLebPEDcaubq6uhUUrjKCp3SztxiOMTmRA5blmeF9@picMFB9l8ZvcTIYdHfnVSaAA82YGHuQ7tto9Ae/2KDK@EJrxyWjHEobdfTlhxaNgQe2exX3N7kjY0nTfXEn52tA4wM1Hkir1TolKfC1APtqBryKDlcR87HZqp3pnLUkAlUo2TjJs@eWemUCbgWPuCGvos9mUuQk6ccPfvkKf2k@b9@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Too slow to do `n>6` on TIO. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔¹η
```

Start with `2ᵏ=1`.

```
⊞υ¹
```

The empty set has one subset sum, `{0}`, represented here as a bitmask of `2⁰=1`.

```
Ｗ¬⊙υ⁼Σ↨κ²Ｘ²θ«
```

Repeat until a subset sum set of size `2ⁿ` is found.

```
≦⊗η
```

Increment `k`.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over all of the sets so far.

```
¿¬＆κ×ηκ
```

If adding `k` to each subset sum (achieved by shifting the bitmask left by `k` bits) does not duplicate any existing sum, then ...

```
⊞υ×⊕ηκ
```

... add the combined subset sum set to the list.

```
»Ｉ⊖Ｌ↨η²
```

Extract the value of `k` needed to get a set of size `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Āi∞.ΔLIãεæODÙQ}à
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//8SAaeKIni7OlExJw6POtcOmT0TDmVF9w6D//zQ) or [verify increasing test cases until it times out](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9vc2FiaWX/W05Ewqk/IiDihpIgIj//xIBp4oieLs6UTMKuw6POtcOmT0TDmVF9w6D/fX0s/w).

**Explanation:**

```python
Āi              # If the (implicit) input is not 0:
  ∞.Δ           #  Find the first positive integer which is truthy for:
     L          #   Pop the integer, and push a list in the range [1,n]
      Iã        #   Take the cartesian power of the input-integer
        ε       #   Map each inner list to:
         æ      #    Take the powerset of this list
          O     #    Sum each inner list
                #    Check if all items are unique by:
           D    #     Duplicating the list
            Ù   #     Uniquify the copy
             Q  #     Check if the lists are still the same
        }à      #   After the map: check if any were truthy (by taking the max)
                #  (after which the integer is output implicitly as result)
                # (implicit else: output the implicit input; the 0)
```